# placing texture on game screen for specific interval of time

Tags: libgdx

I am making a game in Libgdx, in which I want to show and hide a texture for specific interval of time and repeat this process. can I use Timer class for this.
Please give me some example also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what your trying to do here. You could just have a flag in your rendering loop

```
Texture texture;
long lastFlip = 0;
long flipTime = 1000;
boolean display = false;

//..In your rendering loop
if(lastFlip+flipTime > System.currentTimeMillis()){
     display = !display;
     lastFlip = System.currentTimeMillis();
}
if(display){
      spriteBatch.draw(texture,0,0);
}
```

If you want to use the inbuilt actions system in scene2d have a at the following tutorial.  [Tutorial](http://steigert.blogspot.ie/2012/02/3-libgdx-tutorial-scene2d.html). The blog is very good and gives you a good idea of how to use a lot of scene2d features. It might be a little bit out of data beacuse of the changes to scene2d but it will give you the idea you need.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure you got the solution now but instead of using System specific time you should use the Gdx graphics delta time which you already have in the render method. Then compare it with the amount of time for which you want to show the textures.

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely use libGDX wrapper function to read time to avoid eventual incompatibility on different platforms. But code it self can be really simple:

```
if (TimeUtils.millis()%(SHOW_TIME+HIDE_TIME) < SHOW_TIME){
 // render it
}
```

Where SHOW_TIME is number of milliseconds you want your texture displayed and HIDE_TIME is number of milliseconds you want it hidden. No need for extra variables and making it more complicated than this.